# How to force abstract fields in an object to be serialized with newtonsoft.json?

Tags: asp.net, json.net, abstract

If i have an object of class called service, that service contains two normal fields and an abstract field which will be set at run time to value with a type of one of his children. i tried to use:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(service);
```

It did only serialize the two normal fields. However, I can't change my design, so i need to stay with that abstract thing. 
How can i force the converter to serialize the whole object?

Comment: Can you add both the class and abstract class definitions?

Comment: Is your abstract field public or marked with `[JsonProperty]`?

Comment: no it's protected, and when i change it to public it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that it's need to be public. thanks to Brian Rogers.